# return Async/await sync node

Tags: node.js

In this err.length code always returns []. Where am I going wrong?

err.length does not wait for map result

```
router.post('/add', authSigs, async (req, res) => {
  const nds = req.body.nds
  const split = nds.split('\n')
  const err = []

  await split.map(async item => {
    let sub = item.substr(0, 7)
    const checkModel = await modelSerial.findOne({
      'modelNds': sub
    })

    if (!checkModel) err.push(item)
  })

  if (err.length > 0) return res.status(400).send({error: 'Invalid'})
  return res.status(200).send()

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not `await`ing on a `Promise`, you're doing `await [Promise, Promise]` so, your `await` isn't actually waiting for all the promises to resolve, you need to use `Promise.all`, which takes an array of promises.

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that
>   resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have
>   resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It
>   rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
const promises =  split.map(async item => {
  let sub = item.substr(0, 7)
  const checkModel = await modelSerial.findOne({
    'modelNds': sub
  })

  if (!checkModel) err.push(item)
});

await Promise.all(promises);
// Now all promises have been resolved
// err will contain items if there were any errors
```

Comment: Sensational! Let me see if I understood, the promise.all method waits for the resolution of all promises to sequence the code?

Comment: Exactly, it will resolve when all the promises pass to it are resolved.